# Cocos2D - Multiple Tile Maps

Tags: dictionary, cocos2d-iphone, tiles

Is it possible to load multiple tile maps in one layer?
I'm trying to achieve an endless scroll. I was thinking of creating 5 tile maps and when one reaches the end of screen load the next (random) tile map.
Is this even possible?
Is there a better solution to create an endless (random) level with platforms?

Thanks

Comment: This should do the trick: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/5672#post-33913

Comment: [This link](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/8461) might help.